# How to Test onError() callback ? - Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Android SDK for Facebook in my App.Everything working fine !

All I want to do is **test** the onError() use-case. I have some function which opens landing activity with a dialog if it gets onError() callback from facebook sdk.

How to Test onError() callback ?

I did go over facebook SDK documentation it says

```
/**
 * A callback class for the Facebook SDK.
 */
public interface FacebookCallback<RESULT> {
    public void onSuccess(RESULT result);
    public void onCancel();

    /**
     * Called when the dialog finishes with an error.
     *
     * @param error The error that occurred
     */
    public void onError(FacebookException error);
}
```

Either it returns onSuccess() or most of the Facebook error displays on its dialog itself and returns to onCancel() callback when pressing back or cancelling facebook login dialog.

[image]

Comment: That the user typed in a wrong password is not an error. onError happens if something goes wrong. No idea how you would test it

Comment: @WizKid thanks for reply.

Comment: @WizKid in myface book login onError method is calling, kindly tell me how i will handle onError()-->facebookautherizationexception invalid api method.

Comment: Have you tried to activate the airplane mode before logging in?